# Visual Studio 2022 manage nuget packages grayed out

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, nuget

I don't understand why all of a sudden I cannot manage my nuget packages? Anyone has had that problem?

[image]

Comment: Try clean your solution and restart your visual-studio

Comment: Cleaning and restarting did the trick.

Comment: Cleaning a solution and restarting visual studio should never have to be a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, cleaning, rebuilding, and closing and reopening fixes this.

Answer (score 14):

Check your application is Running. if it is running it will not show nuget packages. stop the application and check

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this after manually editing a dependency in the .csproj file.

That caused the project to "unload" so both NuGet Package Manager and the Package Manager Console no longer had a "Default Project" to work with. That greyed out the Pkg Mgr menu option, and left the console unable to select a project to provide any info.

In the "Folder View" this is not obvious, but if you switch back to Solution View you may see `YourProjectName (unloaded)`.

Right-click to "Reload project (with dependencies)" and your NuGet Pkg Mgr should return without having to restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score -1):

Check your VS studio is running as Administrator, I have also faced same issue, It got resolved by running VS as admin